Debian update finds 404 routed through suspicious .ru node
I have a problem updating linux. I received a 404 not found for the IP of the target server which was strange enough. Later I found that traceroute goes through a core backbone.rt.ru node.
Is this a possible BGP hijack?
ru domains nowadays seems very suspicious especially from central Europe.
root@XXXXXXX:~# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org buster/updates InRelease
Hit:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x buster InRelease
Ign:5 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt buster-pgdg InRelease
Err:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt buster-pgdg Release
 ** 404  Not Found [IP: 217.196.149.55 80]**
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt buster-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
root@XXXXXXX:~# ^C
root@XXXXXXX:~#

Here is traceroute:
root@XXXXXXX:~# traceroute 217.196.149.55
traceroute to 217.196.149.55 (217.196.149.55), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  XXXXXXXXXXXXXX  0.465 ms  0.438 ms
 3  164.next4.zicom.pl (185.175.107.164)  6.748 ms  7.108 ms  7.089 ms
 4  et-0-0-18-590.edge5.Warsaw1.Level3.net (213.249.126.109)  7.345 ms  7.777 ms  7.271 ms
 5  ae2.3601.edge5.ber1.neo.colt.net (171.75.8.27)  15.454 ms  15.421 ms  15.572 ms
 6  195.122.181.74 (195.122.181.74)  16.261 ms  16.202 ms  16.138 ms
 7  ae6-2082.ams10.core-backbone.com (80.255.14.33)  27.831 ms  27.767 ms  27.473 ms
 8  core-backbone.rt.ru (81.95.2.150)  26.598 ms  26.359 ms  26.919 ms
 9  * * *
10  185.69.160.214 (185.69.160.214)  37.410 ms  37.011 ms 195.192.211.124 (195.192.211.124)  37.004 ms
11  fabrina.postgresql.org (217.196.149.55)  44.516 ms  44.481 ms *


This isn't a weird problem; you are simply running end of life software.
Debian 10 - Buster - is End of Life and has been EOL for half a year.
Evidently Postgresql stopped building packages for it, and removed their repositories for Buster.
It's probably about time to upgrade to a newer Debian release.
There is no reason to suspect any BGP hijack. It's worth noting that Debian packages uses checksums and cryptographic signatures to validate upgrades, so merely redirecting upgrades should not lead to compromise, but may lead to denial of updates.
